# Doctrine2 order by count many to many with many left join

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have an entity Book and it has too many relations with other entities. now I want to sort a COUNT column of one of many to many relation properties and I use this approach

- [Doctrine2 order by count many to many](http://allan-simon.github.io/blog/posts/doctrine2-order-by-count-many-to-many/)
- [Doctrine2, get entities ordered by a count of a many to many properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512078/doctrine2-get-entities-order-by-count-of-a-many-to-many-property)

but it gave me a wrong response:

- It shows me only one row from any of my join entity because it group by a book id
- Count number is wrong because it count all join rows so number is very large usually

this happen because I have too many left join in my query builder like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->addSelect('bookTranslations')
        ->addSelect('bookGenres')
        ->addSelect('bookCrews')
        ->addSelect('feels')
        ->addSelect('genre')
        ->addSelect('user')
        ->leftJoin('b.translations', 'bookTranslations')
        ->leftJoin('b.bookGenres', 'bookGenres')
        ->leftJoin('b.bookCrews', 'bookCrews')
        ->leftJoin('bookCrews.user', 'user')
        ->leftJoin('bookGenres.genre', 'genre')
        ->leftJoin('b.feels', 'feels')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(bookGenres) AS HIDDEN genreCount')
        ->groupBy('b.id')
    ;
```

I use symfony serializer for responce data

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to show you one row by book because of the *->groupBy('b.id')*, how many rows do you expect by books ?

As for the sorting, you're missing the orderBy :

```
  ->orderBy('genreCount', 'DESC')
```

Comment: I want all books with all its relation, for example, if the book has three genres, I want to show all three genres but it shows me only one genre
and about orderBy, I forgot to add here, I have it in my code

Comment: If you want one a single row per book but with all it's many-to-many relationship, you might need a subquery per many-to-many. Take a look other there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv/42778050#42778050